# In SQL Server, like "use <<DatabaseName>>", how to "use <<ServerName>>" Query command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-connection

In SQL Server, like `use <<DatabaseName>>`, how to give `use <<ServerName>>` query command?

Right Click | Change Connection must be associated to some command. Isn't it. Just curious..

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Is this an issue for querying multiple servers or an automation issue of wanting to have a script deal with multiple servers, albeit on an individual basis?

Comment: Re-phrasing the question:   On New Query window, the Right Click | Change Connection ,  lists all available Servers to connect and its possible to connect/change  the whole window to that specific Server.  Is there any SQL command associated to that menu item ,like " use <database name> ".

Comment: Again, what _exactly_ is the end goal? To run SQL commands from a session on the new <ServerName>? Or just get data from it in your current connection? Do you want to automate something with one SQL script? `USE <DatabaseName>` works because you are connected to a server and switching databases is still the same connection and @@SPID. As per my answer, you can use SQLCMD mode in SSMS with the `:connect` command to change the connection, but this is not a SQL command: it only works in SSMS (in SQLCMD mode) and via SQLCMD.EXE. But knowing _why_ you want to do this might get you a clearer answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you are attempting to fully switch connections<sup>1</sup> within a single script and work with a new connection as opposed to sharing data between connections, then you can do this with SQLCMD mode. This ability / feature is specific to SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and the **SQLCMD.EXE** command-line utility as SQLCMD mode is directives to the client tool (either SSMS or SQLCMD.EXE) and not something that the database engine will be executing (or will even see or ever know about).

You can enable SQLCMD mode in SSMS on a per-session basis by going to the **Query** menu and selecting **SQLCMD Mode**. Once SQLCMD mode is enabled, you can change connections be using the `:connect` command:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName], DB_NAME() AS [DbName]
GO
:connect DifferentServerName
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName], DB_NAME() AS [DbName]
```

**Notes:**

- SQLCMD directives are processed at the beginning of each batch (since the entire batch is then sent to SQL Server for execution). Without using `GO` to separate the batches in the above example, the `:connect` command will take effect before the first `SELECT`. Comment out the `GO` and run again to see the effect.
- When using SQLCMD Mode, Intellisense will not work.
- SQLCMD Mode *cannot* be toggled on or off programmatically, but you can have SQLCMD Mode enabled for all new query windows by going to **Tools | Options | Query Execution** and checking the box for "By default, open new queries in SQLCMD mode".
- There is no SQLCMD mode for the **SQLCMD.EXE** command-line utility; these commands always work in that tool.

<sup>1</sup> Changing the connection logs you out of the current connection. This will drop temporary objects, rollback uncommitted transactions, etc., and local variables will obviously be out of scope (i.e. cannot cross connection boundaries). If statements executed on both servers need to share any info or objects, then you will need to create a Linked Server on one of them and use that Linked Server to connect to the other server on the current connection. Variables and temp objects still can't transfer between them, but you would then at least have the ability to construct Dynamic SQL containing that info to then execute on the remote server, and/or use the local resources in queries that specify four-part names for the remote objects.

Comment: https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Changing%20the%20SQL%20Server%20connection%20within%20an%20SSMS%20Query%20Windows%20using%20SQLCMD%20Mode.aspx

Answer (score 3):

When you connect to Sql Server, you are connecting to a specific server instance. A server instance can host a number of different databases. The `USE Database` command allows you to tell Sql Server which database *in that instance* to use.

A corresponding `USE Server` command does not make sense. Other server instances are not connected to or part of this instance. When you connected to this server, you had to provide credentials that may or may not be valid on other servers, and authentication best practices recommend against preserving those credentials throughout a session, meaning it has no way to re-authorize your connection with a different server.

What you can do is create a linked server, using the [sp_addlinkedserver](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) procedure. Then you must include the server name as part of fully-qualified table name with each query.

Comment: To add: A connection is always to a server. a User server command would do what - create a second connection and relay all commands and data? that would be bad. Magically rewrite the existing connection - why bother? It makes no sense. SQL Server - copntrary to some other databases - always handles connections on a server (instance) level, the database is just the "default" database for a statement (you can actually execute SQL against another database without a use statement).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't any way to `use ServerName` in SQL Server.  You *can* create a linked server and specify that as part of the table name.

Example:

```
SELECT id, name from MyLinkedServer.MyDBName.dbo.TableName
```

If this is something that will work for you take  a look at these articles which go into linked servers in more detail:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35943/How-to-Config-Linked-Servers-in-a-Minute

Answer (score 0):

yes You Must connect with the mandatory Following::

```
SELECT @@SNERVERNAME AS [ServerName], DB_NAME() AS [DbName] FROM sys.tables.connections AGV
GROUP BY DB_NAME()
GO
:connect DifferentServerName
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName], DB_NAME() AS [DbName]
FROM AGV
WHERE CASE WHEN @@SERVERNAME = AGV.SERVER.CONNECTION, 168.192.11.1, 'null'
and
AVG.RECORD_ID between -Inf and Inf
AND
(avg.RECORD_ID is not null or avg.RECORD_ID is null)
```